# how to resolve -bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory at startup?

Tags: bash, startup

I´m a total noob but this is driving me crazy.

I tried to install an app to manage my UPS but since it didn´t worked I remove it, but then these messages start showing at login (ssh)

```
Last login: Mon Nov 23 17:49:43 2020 from 192.168.0.150
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console: No such file or directory
[1]   Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
[2]-  Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
[3]+  Exit 127                /etc/ViewPowerPro/Console
```

any help from Linux gods?

I´m running ubuntu BTW

Comment: Look at the startup files (read `man bash`, the "Startup Files" section). One of them references `/etc/ViewPowerPro/Console`. Remove that reference.

Comment: where can I find that file, I tried to find it yesterday but with no luck, I´m a total newbie...

Comment: Tried to find which file? Open a terminal `Ctrl-Alt-T`, and type `man bash`, then (after the first screen of text appears) `/INVOCATION`. Start reading. Take notes.

Answer (score 0):

Run this terminal command:

```
grep --with-filename --line-number '/etc/ViewPowerPro/Console'  /etc/profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login ~/.profile 2>/dev/null
```

That will show you the file name and line number where the problem is. Further action depends on what you find, but will probably involve deleting that line.

How did you "install" and "uninstall" ViewPowerPro?

I highly recommend installing and using `installwatch`. It's in the `checkinstall` package, so `sudo apt install checkinstall` followed by `man installwatch` will get you started. `installwatch`can be used to log all file accesses by any install process.